# Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error (Laravel 4.1 upgrade)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I recently tried upgrading from Laravel 4.0 to Laravel 4.1, and I am getting the follow error when running php composer.phar update:

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

I am only requiring:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "way/generators": "2.*",
        "madewithlove/laravel-oauth2": "0.4.*"
    },
```

Also, I received this before the error (even though I am running php 5.4.10 in my environment):

```
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-gmp (Install the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) extension in order to speed up arbitrary precision integer arithmetic operations.)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing pear-pear/PHP_Compat (Install PHP_Compat to get phpseclib working on PHP < 4.3.3.)
d11wtq/boris suggests installing ext-readline (*)
d11wtq/boris suggests installing ext-pcntl (*)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

EDIT:

Scripts being used in composer.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade procedure? Running `composer update` won't be enough. http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade

Comment: making the aforementioned changes in the upgrade fixed the problem.  Thank you.  If you would like to answer, I will give you the checkmark.

Comment: Ok, I'll answer, thank you.

Comment: if you are using ubuntu then sudo php5enmod mcrypt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you follow the upgrade procedure? Running `composer update` won't be enough. [laravel.com/docs/upgrade](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade)

Comment: I'll give a point for sending me in the right direction. I updated from 4.0 - 4.1 and never looked for update notes. Encountered the same issue as the poster and followed the update directions. Ran the update again and it worked.

Comment: Just an added note for anyone who might find this later --- the order of changes is important! The upgrade procedure calls for running `composer update` **after** changes are made. I was trying to run it first and running into this problem.

Comment: @Kryten what should I do if I did composer update before making changes?

Comment: @RichBradshaw I just went ahead ignored the errors, made the rest of the changes suggested in the upgrade instructions, then ran `composer update` at the end. It worked fine.

Comment: From 5.5 migration. "With recent improvements to PHP op-code caching, the optimize Artisan command is no longer needed. You should remove any references to this command from your deployment scripts as it will be removed in a future release of Laravel."

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you can try this command:

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Except this was the actual solution that helped in my case.

Comment: Worked for me in Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 6):

Try to remove **/bootstrap/compiled.php** (I was in trouble downgrading Laravel 4.2 > 4.1)

Then try to `composer update`, it should work.

Good luck

Answer (score 5):

Try the following in your composer.json. 
There **clear-compiled** handling the **pre-update-cmd** event is your error you might clear it.

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
```

Try to run again the following command:

```
 php composer.phar update
```

Comment: After making this change (see edit above), I am still receiving the error: Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


                      
  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me:

After updating composer.jsonper the upgrade guide, to get all updated repo's:

`composer update --no-scripts`

Then: `composer dump-autoload -o`

Then, I ran an update again so my pre/post update scripts can run: `composer update`

App loads in browser and all my tests pass again using 5.2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If using laravel 5 , then the correct file to delete is `services.json` in `bootstrap/cache` folder , this error is caused when composer is corrupt due to unfinished update ,

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other answers work, please try this:

```
"pre-update-cmd": [],
"post-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled",
    "php artisan optimize"
],
```